# What is rule position of an event rule in Eventbridge documentation of Serverless

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-serverless, aws-event-bridge

In Eventbridge documentation of Serverless (https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/event-bridge), there is mention of rule position in event rule default naming convention as follows:

> eventBridge events by default are named with the lambda function's
> name with a suffix for the rule position.

I want to know what is meant by this "rule position" as I could not find any AWS documentation regarding this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "rule position" refers to the position of the rule in the `events` property of the Lambda function. Let's say you have the following `serverless.yml` (is not complete, just the relevant parts):

```
service: my-eventbridge-service

functions:
  myFunction:
    handler: index.handler
    events:
      - eventBridge:
          schedule: cron(0 10 * * ? *)
          input:
            key1: value1
      - eventBridge:
          schedule: cron(0 12 * * ? *)
          input:
            key1: value2
```

The the EventBridge rules created would be named `my-eventbridge-service-dev-myFunction-rule-1` and `my-eventbridge-service-dev-myFunction-rule-2`.

You can set the `name` property to override this behavior.

Comment: Thank you so much Andres for such a nice explanation. I have a follow-up question. If the events array in serverless.yml of your example is something like:

**events:
  - sqs:
      arn:
        Fn::GetAtt:
          - AuthQ
          - Arn
      batchSize: 1
  - eventBridge:
      schedule: rate(27 minutes)**

then, whether the rule so created for eventbridge would be like: my-eventbridge-service-dev-myFunction-rule-2 ?

Comment: Yes, indeed, that's correct. I suggest that you use a meaningful name for your rules whenever possible.

Comment: Ok Andres, got it. Makes sense to me. Thank you so much for your help once again.